# Determining the continuity of $[x]-[-x]$

Tags: functions, continuity

I am trying to find the continuity of $[x]-[-x]$ where $x\in\Bbb{R}$ and $[\;]$ denotes the greatest integer function. Here is what I have done;

Let $f(x)=[x]-[-x].$ It is obvious that if $b$ is an integer, then

> $$\lim_{x\to b-} f(x)=\lim_{x\to b-}[x] -\lim_{x\to b-}[-x] =(b-1)-[-(b-1)]=2b-2.$$
>   Also, 
>   $$\lim_{x\to b+} f(x)=\lim_{x\to b+}[x] -\lim_{x\to b+}[-x] =b-(-b)=2b,$$
>   and 
>   $$f(b)=[b] -[-b] =b-(-b)=2b.$$

This shows that $f(x)$ is not continuous for all integer values of $x$. Is it also discontinuous for all $x\in\Bbb{R}?$

I would like to know if I'm right. If yes, can anyone also help extend it to $\Bbb{R}?$ I would be very glad for that help.

Comment: It's obviously continuous except perhaps at the integers, because the greatest integer function is continuous everywhere except the integers.

Comment: @ saulspatz: Thank you for the prompt reply. So, I'm I right?

Comment: I haven't read your proof.  I was just answering the question, "Is it discontinuous of all $x\in\mathbb R?"

Comment: @saulspatz: Okay!

Comment: No, I don't think the proof is correct.  As $x\to b-,$ we have $-x\to -b+$, and similarly for the right-hand limits, so you need to redo your calculations.  You might [sketch a graph](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+floor(x)%2Bfloor(-x))

Comment: Oops.  That was the graph of the wrong function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case my comment wasn't clear, your calculations are incorrect, though your conclusion is right.  The first line should read $$
\lim_{x\to b-} f(x)=\lim_{x\to b-}[x] -\lim_{-x\to-b+}[-x] =(b-1)-(-b)=2b-1$$

Now correct the second line similarly.

$$\lim_{x\to b+} f(x)=\lim_{x\to b+}[x] -\lim_{-x\to -b-}[-x] =b-(-b-1)=2b+1$$

Compare this to the [graph](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20floor(x)-floor(-x)) (of the right function this time!) on Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: @ saulspatz: Thank you very much!

Comment: @Mike My pleasure